# Clicking Javascript confirmation button in VBA script

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, messagebox

The purpose of my code is to run a report on a website with specified criteria. I want to search for all of the "distance" criteria, which prompts a message box asking if I'm sure. I want my code to be able to click the "Ok" button. However, my code stops running once the "Submit" button is hit and is hung until the "Ok" button is hit.

Note: I cannot change the HTML or JavaScript

Here's the VBA code

```
Sub Data_Grab()

'Open Internet Explorer and webpage
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "insert website here"

'wait for page to finish loading
Do While IE.Busy
Loop

'get a reference to the search form by finding the id in the web page's object model
Dim daysAs Object
Dim city As Object
Set days= IE.Document.getElementByID("age"): days.Value = "10"
Set city= IE.Document.getElementByID("location"): city.Value = "LA"    

'click the search button
With IE.Document
    Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each e In elems    
        If (e.getAttribute("value") = "Submit") Then
            e.Click
            Exit For
        End If 
    Next e
End With 
End Sub
```

The relevant HTML/JavaScript code from the website source

```
if (!distanceSelect) {
    proceed = confirm("Are you sure you wish to search all " + question + "? Performance issues may occur.");
} else {proceed = true;}
```

And

```
<input class="contentarea" type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="javascript:loadReport();" />
```

I've tried numerous different solution, such as SendKeys and creating a ShellScript, but I haven't been able to get any of them to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to override `confirm` with `execScript`:

```
Dim ie As Object, win As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "https://stackoverflow.com"

Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Set win = ie.Document.parentWindow
win.execScript "window.confirm = function(){return true;};"
```