# VBA & Internet Explorer Automation. Click "OK" in msgbox popup

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation

When clicking button "Submit All" a popup titled "Message from Webpage" pops up with a "OK" or "Cancel" selection.

This popup stops my VBA code, and it doesn't resume until human intervention closes the popup. I have scoured the internet for days, and I can't find a working solution to this. SendKey doesn't work because it doesn't get executed until the VBA code resumes. I've tried to sleep the sendkey and that didn't work either.

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim tRows As Long
Dim searchtxt As Object, myie As Object

Set myie = New InternetExplorerMedium
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

With tbl.DataBodyRange
    tRows = .Rows.Count + 2
End With


CreateObject ("internetexplorer.application")
For i = 2 To tRows - 1




With myie
    .Navigate Range("G" & i)
    .Visible = True
    Do While .Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Do While .ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End With
  
myie.document.getElementById("colorCategory").Value = "P"

  
Set searchtxt = myie.document.getElementsByName("comment")(0)
searchtxt.Value = Range("F" & i)


With myie.document

    Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each e In elems

        If (e.getAttribute("value") = "Submit All") Then
        e.Click
        
            Exit For
        End If

    Next e

End With

    Range("H" & i).Value = "Complete"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    

Next i
    myie.Quit
    Set searchtext = Nothing
    Set myie = Nothing
```

The button html

```
<input class="tc" type="button" value="Submit All" onclick="submitComment()">
```

Function the button calls:

```
  function submitComment() {
        
         
        if(validateInput()) {
            
        currPartColor = document.dccmpForm.colorCategory.value ;
           
           
           if ( currPartColor == 'P'){                   
                if (confirm("Press the Ok button to Change the color, otherwise press Cancel")){
                   document.dccmpForm.userAction.value ="U";
                   document.dccmpForm.action='/dccmp/CommentScreen.do'; 
                   document.dccmpForm.submit();
                   toggleDiv('loading',1);
                   return;
                }
                
            }else{               
                
                  document.dccmpForm.userAction.value ="U";
                  document.dccmpForm.action='/dccmp/CommentScreen.do'; 
                  document.dccmpForm.submit();
                  toggleDiv('loading',1);
                   return;
            
            }  

            
    }else { 
          return;
        }
  
  
  }
```

Tim Williams Suggestion:

```
Dim ie As Object, win As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With myie.document
        Set win = ie.document.parentWindow
        Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each e In elems
    
            If (e.getAttribute("value") = "Submit All") Then
            e.Click
            win.execScript "window.confirm = function(){return true;};"
                Exit For
            End If
    
        Next e
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165674/clicking-javascript-confirmation-button-in-vba-script shows how you can override the Confirm() function to just return true without popping up a dialog.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams I took your suggestion, and added an edit to the bottom of my original post. Did I add it in the correct spot? If so, I am no longer getting a pop-up, but its also not clicking either. Nor is it looping now. Would it make sense to <pre>'Set myie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")' <code>

Comment: You have to override the Confirm function *before* submitting the form.

Comment: Also if you use `Option Explicit` it will warn you about problems like your `ie`/`myie` mismatch.

Comment: I agree with Tim's suggestion. You need to put the `win.execScript "window.confirm = function(){return true;};"` before you click the submit button. Then it can override the confirm function and click the submit button successfully.